# Why is the following code non-deterministic?

Tags: c++, optimization, iterator, timing

I was going over some interview prep questions, and I saw this one in C++, asking why the following code is non-deterministic. I have no idea why, and nothing online seems to explain things. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
void func(std::vector<int>& input) {
       static int i = 0;
       auto start = getTimestamp();
       for (auto it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); it++) {
            *it = i;
       }
       auto end = getTimestamp();
       cout << start<< end<< input.size());
   }
```

As a followup, another question is: how does "getTimestamp()" affect the timing measurement?

Answer (score 2):

The function is deterministic in that it always modifies its input in the same way: it zeroes out `input`.

However processes can get swapped out, CPUs clock up, clock down, the cache can be hot or cold, etc. There's hundreds of reasons why one time the code might run faster and slower another time. This makes the time taken non-deterministic from run to run.

Since it explicitly prints out this timing information, it's non-deterministic.

Comment: Can you explain a little about these concepts of CPUs clocking up/down, cache being hot/cold, and some of the other hundreds of reasons why this may be non-deterministic? I'm trying to learn more about optimizing C++ code for low-latency applications

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees optimizing for low latency is something that could take an entire semester course with labs to explain completely. There are a lot of "Profile and verify" cycles.

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees: Consider modern 80x86: best case is you have a core by yourself and get "turboboost" (CPU running at maybe 4.5 GHz), and worst case is thermal throttling downclocking CPU to 12.5% of nominal clock (e.g. maybe 400 Mhz) where you're sharing a core with something else; leading to an "about 20 times" performance difference between best and worst case for CPU alone.

Comment: Can anyone guide me to some resources? Everything I look up seems to be too superficial ex: "unroll your loops", "branching is expensive". I'm looking for more low-level discussions. I understand that this may be a long and hard topic, but I would like to learn.

Comment: To make everything Brendan said more fun, the CPU is superscalar. This means it tries to execute multiple instructions at once. If any of those cause a pipeline stall that will cause variance. Add Symmetric multi-threading on top of that and another thread could cause that stall. Or you could get port stalled because modern CPUs are closer to multiple CPUs internally.

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees we could try to explain this but the CPU complexity [alone](https://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf) is massive. Not counting other system variables like bus locks, memory bandwidth, NIC issues etc.

Comment: To add to that; there's IRQs (from devices, and from other CPUs) interrupting at "random" times and various things that trigger "system management mode" stealing CPU time. Then there's the whole "memory hierarchy" (all the way from L1 caches down to swap space), with various things (NUMA, the possibility of "ECC error correction", GPU stealing some RAM bandwidth) making differences in how long it takes CPU to access RAM. Then there's the operating system - scheduler doing task switches between your software and other software whenever it feels like it, and virtual memory doing its trickery.

Comment: That said... there are situations where all of the things we've said are irrelevant: Embedded generally has the option to run CPUs with built in ram, that is always real time, has no virtual memory, and limited IRQs. In these cases generally these CPUs are not superscalar and have very well known and understood instruction times and latencies.

Comment: Can you guide me to some more resources about this? I"m not sure what you mean by "embedded", embedded systems? processors? This is all great information, I'm just trying to learn even more, thanks!

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees take a look at the PRU-ICSS built into some TI chips as an example of highly deterministic processors.

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees if you want to learn about that I'd suggest researching the [MOS6502](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502) or the [Z80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilog_Z80). The electronics stackexchange might be a good place too. The [PIC family may interest as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC_microcontrollers)